# Adjust height of the views when no drawables are used

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a simple login screen as follows:

[image: login image]

above screenshot was taken on 4.7" screen size

and following screen shot was taken on 5.5" screen size:

[image: same login image]

no image is used in this screen ,so no chance for hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi .
Just a simple Edit-text's and Text-view's and Buttons used in this.

I want the same screen displayed, in both screen sizes.
can anyone help me for this ?
How should i do this?

following is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:titleTextColor="@color/loginColorPrimary"
    app:title="Login"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_login_email_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/et_login_rect_shape"
            android:hint="@string/et_login_email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="@dimen/et_login_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/loginEditTextHintColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/et_login_text_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_login_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/et_login_email_id"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/et_login_rect_shape"
            android:hint="@string/et_login_mobile_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="@dimen/et_login_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/loginEditTextHintColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/et_login_text_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/et_login_mobile"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_red"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_login_text_size" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_forgot_pw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_login"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tvLoginForgotPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/tvLoginForgotPw"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tv_login_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_or"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_login_forgot_pw"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Or"
            android:textColor="@color/tvLoginColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tv_login_or_text_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_login_or"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@color/btnLoginWithFacebook"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_login_text_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Google"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_facebook"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@color/btnLoginWithGoogle"
            android:text="Login with google+"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_login_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_do_not_account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_Google"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Do not have an account? Register!"
            android:textColor="@color/tvLoginColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tv_login_text_size" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_for_btn_buyers_sellers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_login_do_not_account"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_one"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_login_background_rect_shape"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Button ONE"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/tvLoginColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_login_text_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_two"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_login_background_rect_shape"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Button TWO"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/tvLoginColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_login_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: use weight concept in this type of layouts

Answer (score 0):

Use weight concept and make the height 0dp so that layout height expand and compress according to the height of the screen.

Comment: but what about the top margins though height is 0dp? you can't neglect such things , lets assume in above screen i have given 0dp height and weight as 1 but top margins remains the same and eventually the result is same. I tried that also.

Comment: try to give height 0dp and weight concept within the scroll view, and take linear-layout inside scroll, and our layout will always scroll on small sizes devices,you can fix header or footer component but when screen size small then content will scroll/hide inside the header or footer also.

Answer (score 0):

```
By using weight concept 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_login_email_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter Email id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/loginEditTextHintColor"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_login_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/et_login_email_id"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter mobile number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/loginEditTextHintColor"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/et_login_mobile"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/btn_rounded_red"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_forgot_pw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_login"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="forgot password"
            android:textColor="#87D1ED"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_or"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_login_forgot_pw"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Or"
            android:textColor="#434343"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_login_or"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3C5899"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Google"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_facebook"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C52C2E"
            android:text="Login with google+"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_do_not_account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_Google"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Do not have an account? Register!"
            android:textColor="#A6A6A6"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_for_btn_buyers_sellers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_one"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Button ONE"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#A6A6A6"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_two"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Button TWO"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#A6A6A6"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have done this already, and the views are cut if you increase the top margin for each view. So are there any other ways?

Comment: No I don't think any other way for create layout, but i was run it moto e2 and its showing  fine. if you want to give margin to top then you have to change the weight. otherwise you have to use ScrollView.